C# gives different hash of inline string than Script hasher for Content Security Policy
I have a C# string that has been built up with a stringbuilder. There are 2 lines that have the output:
Line1
Line2

I hash with this code:
public static string GetSha256Hash(string input)
{
    using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}

CSPLite creates the correct following hash:

However .net (C# or VB.Net below) creates a different hash due to the likely the line breaks that is handled differently

If I copy and paste the output of that same string, then i get the correct hash

How can I adapt the C# string in order to create the same hash as what CSP is creating?

There is probably a difference in whitespace. Either a trailing linebreak or one system treating line break as \n and the other as \r and \n.
